# Creating and pushing dynamic objects into a vector

Tags: c++

I am concerned about creating and then pushing the dynamic objects into vector of pointers. I would like to know how to implement this correctly to avoid any kind of memory leaks. Here's what I have:

```
//THIS CREATES VECTOR
vector <combustion_car*> combustion_car_list;
//THIS IS CREATING AND PUSHING THE OBJECT
combustion_car* temporary=new combustion_car;
                temporary->create();
                combustion_car_list.push_back(temporary);
                cout<<"Object added"<<endl;
                temporary=NULL;
                delete temporary;
//THIS DELETES OBCJET FROM VECTOR
combustion_car_list.erase(combustion_car_list.begin() + (choice-1));
```

Comment: If you don't need to use pointers then don't. If you do, then use a smart pointer and avoid manual memory management.

Comment: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to `NULL`. Also *never* `delete` a null pointer.

Comment: You should consider skipping the pointer part and just use [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: if you do manual memory management, first use delete statement and the assign nullptr or NULL to your temporary object.

Comment: @AneuryPerez The problem is it's been pushed into the vector, so that invalidates that pointer. Best to just leave it.

Comment: That `erase` does *not* delete objects. It deletes *pointers* and abandons the objects. That is a memory leak, plain and simple.

Comment: Unrelated: `temporary->create();` seems like a bad idea. Except for relatively uncommon cases where two-phase construction is advantageous or necessary, the constructor should do all of the creating.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, I do need to use pointers. This code is only a small part of my project. So If I use a smart pointer I dont have to worry about cleaning up my memory and  while creating an object I can simply end my code on line cout<<"object added"<<endl; ?

Comment: @user4581301 my class is multiply inherited and has a lot of variables that have to be manually set, that's why I use create(); instead of constructor.

Comment: @tadman "*Also never delete a null pointer*" - why would you say that?  A null pointer is *perfectly safe* to call `delete` on.

Comment: @MarcelBuczkowski you should not be `delete`'ing a pointer you just `push_back()`'ed into a container. That leaves the container holding a **dangling pointer to invalid memory**, which *will* crash your code later on when you try to use that object you `delete`'d.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's an utterly pointless thing to do when you know it's null, as in this code. Perhaps I should've been more specific as you point out.

Comment: @tadman `delete` checks for null for you, so doing the same check manually is redundant.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, I mean when the line above is literally `ptr = nullptr` then `delete ptr` is just plain pointless.

Comment: @tadman obviously doing `temporary=NULL; delete temporary;` is backwards, it should be `delete temporary; temporary=NULL;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your original code sample, following are some suggested modifications to make it safely avoid memory leaks.

1. Rather than use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of bare pointers, use a collection of [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) objects:

   ```
   //THIS CREATES VECTOR
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<combustion_car>> combustion_car_list;
   ```
2. Create your temporary object using a call to [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), and transfer its ownership to the container using [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

   ```
   //THIS IS CREATING AND PUSHING THE OBJECT
   std::unique_ptr<combustion_car> temporary=std::make_unique<combustion_car>();
   temporary->create();
   combustion_car_list.push_back(std::move(temporary));
   std::cout<<"Object added"<<std::endl;
   ```
3. Remove the element at `combustion_car_list[choice]` (`choice-1` is incorrect, but also dangerous because it could be `0`, yielding an iterator value that is before `combustion_car_list.begin()`):

   ```
   //THIS DELETES OBJECT FROM VECTOR
   combustion_car_list.erase(combustion_car_list.begin() + choice);
   ```

You'll also notice explicit use of `std` namespace throughout; see: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6610379)

Comment: I think this answer is good, but I would add some context on why `unique_ptr` is a better choice and what ownership is.

Comment: @BobMorane Appreciate the constructive feedback - will amend when I get a moment.

Comment: @PhilBrubaker Thank you so much, now everything is clear and I see how convenient it is to use inteligent pointers rather than the raw ones.

Comment: @MarcelBuczkowski glad it was helpful!